# Como enviar form mas remover campos nulos

Tags: php, html

Como faço para mandar um form por exemplo via GET ou POST, mas sem enviar os campos que estiverem nulos?

Para deixar bem claro, eu quero que o form seja submetido mesmo com alguns campos vazios, mas que esses campos vazios não sejam enviados.

Vamos supor que eu tenha o form abaixo, gostaria que somente o campo1 fosse enviado.

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="campo1" value="1">
   <input type="text" name="campo2" value="">
</form>
```

Porque caso envie com ele vazio, na url ficara por exemplo ?campo1=1&campo2=, e quero que fique apenas ?campo1=1 e somente quando o campo 2 tiver algum valor que enviaria o valor dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim como o [Caique comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/238778/5878), você pode, com JavaScript, adicionar a propriedade `disabled` no momento que o formulário é submetido, assim o navegador não incluirá os campos em branco:

```
const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    for (let input of this.elements) {
        if (!input.value) {
            input.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        }
    }
});
```

O mesmo acontece se definir a propriedade `name` para nulo:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
    for (let input of this.elements) {
        if (!input.value) {
            input.setAttribute("name", "");
        }
    }
});
```

**Comentários sobre o código**

Através do `document.getElementById` conseguimos obter a referência em JS do formulário no DOM, ou seja, `form` será o formulário que desejamos trabalhar - perceba que para isso será ncessário definir o atributo `id` no mesmo. Após, utilizando `addEventListener`, adicionamos uma função que sempre será executada quando o evento `submit` do formulário for disparado, isto é, quando o formulário for submetido - na verdade o evento `submit` é executado imediatamente antes da submissão efetiva do formulário pelo navegador. Nesta função, então, percorremos todos os elementos (campos) do formulário em questão através de um laço de repetição `for`, iterando sobre `this.elements`. O `this`, neste caso, faz referência ao objeto `form`. Assim, `input` será a referência a cada campo do formulário, então verificamos se o respectivo valor `input.value` é válido e, quando não for, definimos a propriedade `disabled` como verdadeira do mesmo. Um campo com a propriedade `disabled` definida é ignorado pelo navegador quando o formulário é submetido, por esse motivo que os campos em branco não são enviados.

Comment: Anderson, funcionou amigo muito obrigado. Se não for pedir de mais, será que você poderia me explicar o que você fez ai? pois eu tinha tentado anteriormente algo parecido com jquery e não tive sucesso.

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos tentei explicar, veja se ficou suficientemente claro.

Answer (score 3):

Caso você só queria ocultar da `URL` basta utilizar `POST`.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

Caso você realmente não queira receber esses valores então você pode fazer isso de algumas formas:

1. Adicionar a propriedade `disabled`;
2. Remover a propriedade `name` (uma vez que ela é necessária para a requisição no lado do servidor);

Para o seu caso as duas opções acima só devem ser aplicadas se no momento do envio os campos estiverem vazios.

Então imagino que você tenha de criar um Javascript para captar o evento de `submit`, verificar se o(s) campo(s) são vazio(s) e atribuir o `disabled` ou remover a propriedade `name`.

```js
$("#btnEnviar").on("click", function(){
  event.preventDefault(); //Evito o submit para nosso teste.
  
  //atribuir disabled
  if(!$("#campo1").val()){
    $("#campo1").attr("disabled", true);
  }
  
  //Ou modificar a propriedade name
  if(!$("#campo2").val()){
    console.log("hi");
    $("#campo2").prop("name", "");
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form  action="#" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="campo1" id="campo1" value="1" />
   <input type="text" name="campo2" id="campo2" value="" />
   
   <button type="submit" name="btnEnviar" id="btnEnviar">
       Enviar
   </button>
</form>
```